# Skip a item in repeater control if it is blank

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I am using repeater control of asp.net . It i am using two columns Query and reply from database table to populate the data.If Query or reply column is blank then i don't want it to repeat with blank row. So how can i check for it and skip the displaying of the row. I mean if reply is not there the query will come twice together skipping a reply in between.

Below is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 40px">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <HeaderTemplate>
<table style=" border:1px solid #df5015; width:500px" cellpadding="0">
<tr style="background-color:#df5015; color:White">
<td colspan="2">
<b>Chat</b> 
</td>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

<tr style="background-color:#EBEFF0">
<td>
<table style="background-color:#EBEFF0;border-top:1px dotted #df5015; width:500px" >
<tr>
<td>
Query:

<asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Query") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>

</td>
</tr> 
</table> 
</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

Reply
<asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Reply") %>'/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Service_WinmanConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Query], [Reply] FROM [WebCalls]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I mean if rows of table are like shown in below image

[image]

Then for the code i have written will give output like shown below

[image]

Here third row does not contain value for reply column.So in the design output Reply: is blank(see image) . But i want that label "Reply:" not to come. So the output will be like
After `Query:c`  it will display `Query:d` instead of printing `Reply:`(which is blank).So i want reply: label to not display in that case.
It is just like chat where if one replies twice together it will display two times.
So how it can be achieved?

Comment: I'd solve this by filtering these rows in the database query.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious solutions...

One is to restrict the amount of data being returned from your database using filtering on the query.

The other is to use the `ItemDataBound` of the repeater...

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_onItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
  If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    If e.Item.DataItem("Query") Is DBNull.Value OrElse e.Item.DataItem("Reply") Is DBNull.Value Then
      e.Item.Visible = False
    End
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have updated my question.Please check.Your code is just to check empty data i guess.